# Bootstrap navbar active class using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

using the below bootstrap navigation bar.

```
        <div class="navbar-default">              
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="Link1">Link1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="Link2">Link2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

using below jquery to activate the links

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.nav > li').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('ul.nav > li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

when use the above code the active class works fine but the page is not getting loaded.

when comment e.preventDefault(); the page is getting loaded but the active class is not working.

Comment: You should have to set the class active for particular menu item after page has been loaded.

Comment: You're adding the active class on a click handler; you could probably get what you want by adding a `window.location = $(this).attr('href');`, but why? The class will be added just before the page unloads (following the href).

Comment: can you show me the code how to do that?

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` prevents a default action from occurring.  In this case it makes your links non-functional.  And of course, when you load a new page nothing in the above code would work, because the click event happened on X.html and you are now on Y.html (for example).

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, let's assume there are two HTML pages: `page1.html` and `page2.html`. Ignoring your JavaScript, when you click a link on `page1.html`, it goes to `page2.html`. If you set the `active` class to the appropriate link in `page2.html`, it should work (set the link going to `page2.html` as the active link).

In your JavaScript, `e.preventDefault()` prevents the default action. In this case, it stops the webpage from redirecting to the new link. Even if you somehow managed to make it work, when you load `page2.html`, whatever JavaScript you have run previously on `page1.html` (setting the active class) is **not** transferred to `page2.html`. So that JavaScript is useless.

Simply editing `page2.html`'s active link is the way to do it, rather than trying to apply Javascript to `page1.html` and transferring it to `page2.html`.